# Calling Code Behind Methods in Padarn

Tags: padarn

Does Padarn support the call to methods that exist in the Code Behind from the ASPX page?

For example (pseudo):

MyPage.cs Code Behind.

```
protected string GetData()
{
 return("Here's the data");
}
```

MyPage.aspx calls the GetData() method that lives in its code behind...

```
<%= this.GetData() %>
```

When I attempt something like the above example, the response that is displayed in the browser is reads...

[translated asp]

instead of "Here's the data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, ctacke answered this question in a cross-post thread at [OpenNETCF Community](http://community.opennetcf.com/forums/t/12652.aspx) forum...

> No, ASP 3.0-style code doesn't work. 
>   You're better off rendering the page
>   in Render and calling the method
>   there.  You could do your own request
>   handler that did this kind of parsing,
>   but I think it would be way more work
>   than it would be worth.